# How to inline modify a single element in an array based on its index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example, I have `array = [1,2,3,4,5]`

I want to change the value of the element with index 4.

In multiple steps I could do:

```
> array[4] = 'new value'
=> "new value"
> array
=> [1,2,3,4, "new value"]
```

But is there a way to do this inline? Something like

```
array.map! { |x| x == 5 ? "new value" : x }
```

but using the index number not the value.

I've searched around and read through the ruby-docs, but I'm not sure what I should be looking for!

Comment: Why the need to do this inline if it works doing it the first way?

Comment: I think the OP wants to change the value of the entry whose value is 5, irrespective of the first example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
array.tap{ |ar| ar[4] = "new value" }
```